# Downloading file from Redirecting link

Tags: c#

I know how to download a file through web client but the thing is I am downloading a .rar file from a link and the link is being redirected 2 to 3 times i use webclient and httpwebrequest

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(Completed);
webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(ProgressChanged);
webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("http://www.example.com"), "setup.rar");
```

webclient can download the file but corrupted and

I have used the HttpWebRequest
it can get the link redirected but won't download the file

Answer (score 0):

The Webclient class is not a browser. If it sees a 3xx request it will not automatically respond to it. It is up to the caller to decide what to do next.

You can try writing a custom WebClient class to enable auto redirects.

```
public class WebClientEx : WebClient
{
    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)base.GetWebRequest(address);
        request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
        return request;
    }
}
```

and then:

```
using (var webClient = new WebClientEx())
{
    webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(Completed);
    webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(ProgressChanged);
    webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("http://www.example.com"), "setup.rar");
}
```

I haven't tested this but give it a go and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it wont worked it just downloading the same corrupted rar file which gives error of "the archive either is unknown format or damaged"

Comment: Can you post the real url to reproduce this behaviour?